# Jquery Parent Child Selector Improvement

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent

I am learning Jquery and hope to do things better. I have found a solution, and want to see how a seasoned veteran would do it... If there is more eloquence, so to speak.

The problem is I have a widget that rests in a table row. The widget has the same classes as all the other 20 widget. When someone clicks on a particular widget, only that widget should change.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="deal-widget">
  <div class="deal-widget-left">
    <div class="deal-widget-left-countdown">
      <span class="totalcoupons">500</span> of <span class="maxcoupons">500</span>
    </div>
    <div class="deal-widget-left-remain">
      Remaining
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="deal-widget-right is_open">
    <a href="/deal/claim/1113" class="deal-link">Claim It!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my stab at the JQuery:

```
Drupal.behaviors.plusone = function (context) {
  $('a.deal-link:not(.deal-processed)', context).click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parents('div.deal-widget');
    var originalVote = parent.children('div.deal-widget-left').children('div.deal-widget-left-countdown').children('span.totalcoupons').text();
    var originalVoteInt =  parseInt(originalVote);
    var voteSaved = function (data) {
      parent.children('div.deal-widget-left').children('div.deal-widget-left-countdown').children('span.totalcoupons').html(originalVoteInt - data.total_votes);
      parent.children('div.deal-widget-right').html(data.voted);
      parent.children('div.deal-widget-right').removeClass('is_open').addClass(data.votedClass);
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: this.href,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: voteSaved,
      data: 'js=1'
    });
    return false;
  })
  .addClass('deal-processed');
}
```

Is there a better way of selecting parent then second set of children to a clicked-upon object than this?

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using:

```
var parent = $(this).closest('div.deal-widget');
var originalVote = parent.find('span.totalcoupons').text();
```

`closest()` searches the ancestor elements for the first element that matches the provided selector; `find()` searches the descendent elements for those that match the provided selector.

While `closest()` returns only one match (the *closest*/*first* element that matches the selector) it's important to note that `find()` may return multiple elements.

---

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: .closest() works like a charm! Thanks for the diff method. I'm using it. -- Joe

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to have helped =) I would suggest that if this, or another, answer solved your problem you should consider accepting (click on the tick next to the answer) or up-voting (click the upwards arrow to the left). It's not compulsory, but is appreciated by the community.

Comment: I clicked the checkmark and it turned green. I haven't earned the status to vote up or down yet. But when I do.... Joe

Answer (score 1):

Use find()?  So:

```
var originalVote = parent.children('div.deal-widget-left').children('div.deal-widget-left-countdown').children('span.totalcoupons').text();
```

becomes:

```
var originalVote = parent.find('span.totalcoupons').text();
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for here...